# Kibana - Limit "sum" metric on data table

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

In Kibana's visualize screen I'm trying to create a "sum" metric and I would like to limit the values of this sum (between 0.1 and X), but I only get to limit the field values before aggregation is performed.

I have designed a simple metric that consists in the aggregation of a field called Timestamp_Med. I don't know how to make the filter properly, 
so I only get the filter applied on the field, but not on the sum metric.

**For example**, if I have these rows:

```
   
ID  Session_Id  Timestamp_Med
1      1            5
2      1            7 
3      1            3
4      2            6
5      3            0
6      3            2
7      4            15
8      5            4
9      6            0
10     6            4
```

My metric must sum the Timestamp_Med field, group by the Session_Id

```
Session_Id  Sum(Timestamp_Med)
    1              15
    2              6
    3              2
    4              15
    5              4
    6              4
```

I apply the filter: (Timestamp_Med: [1 TO 5]) I get the results for the original records with ID 1,3,5,6,8,9 and 10 with the next session values for the metric:

```
Session_Id  Sum(Timestamp_Med) 
    1             8
    3             2
    5             4
    6             4
```

But I want to filter values in **"Sum(Timestamp_Med)"**, not in "Timestamp_Med", and get:

```
Session_Id  Sum(Timestamp_Med) 
    3             2
    5             4
    6             4
```

Could I do this filter? Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have tried to give more information about my problem .
Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer to the above question is that it isn't possible in Kibana at this time.  You'd need to do a bucket pipeline aggregation to do it I believe and that's not supported yet: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4584

Comment: I agree with @Alcanzar, I don't think that's possible with Kibana

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try to find other solution.